# Comparing current DateTime to a value in MySQL

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli

I've been trying to add in an expiry for password reset requests.

When the user requests a password request at the moment, it stores an expiration date in the database as NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY - so exactly 2 days from now.

When the user comes back to the page by following their reset link, it checks the reset key exists and then runs a series of if statements, one of which I want to test whether the current DateTime is greater than that of which is in the database and if it is then display an error message.

I've tried a raft of ways as most tend to suggest using SQL to evaluate this. The most recent and most popular from what I've found was to do the following:

```
"SELECT *, DATE(`Expiration`) > DATE(NOW()) AS is_current FROM password_reset WHERE Reset_link='$key'"
```

This way you could then feed the results in to a variable and test it in the if statement as `is_current` would either be 0 or 1, i.e:

```
if ($result_check_row['is_current']){
         echo '<div class="warning">Your password reset request has now expired. Please request a new one by completing the form again.''</div>';
     }
```

I haven't had any luck with this, or any of the other things I've tried which include creating a timestamp via PHP to test against this.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong or suggest a good alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query, it will produce date difference between current date and expiry date...

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DATE(`Expiration`), DATE(NOW())) AS DiffDate FROM password_reset WHERE Reset_link='$key'"
```